# E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, video, codec

I turned on the "Video Capture" option in VirtualBox, recorded a video in webm format, shut down the virtual machine and tried to play this video, but I got this error in the Totem video player:

```
An error occured. Could not demultiplex stream`
```

However, mpv video player can play this video. This implies that some codecs are missing. I decided to install the package `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` and I got following result:

```
hubot@debian:~$ sudo apt install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0

E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' has no installation candidate
```

So, I decided to install package `libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0` because this package can replace it and I got again the same result:

```
hubot@debian:~$ sudo apt install libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0' has no installation candidate
```

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 9 Stretch on my laptop.

How can I make totem play this video?

Answer (score -1):

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10 gstreamer0.10-plugins
```